# How to filter choice field by the type of user in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have created a customer `User` model and I have another model `Enquiry`. In the `Enquiry` model there is one service field that has relation with the custom `User` model. I want the field service to be filtered by the user type. I want that the service field will on show me the staff user choice only.

Here is my models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=254,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True) 
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_Customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Service_Provider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    

    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
    def get_username(self):
        return self.username



class Enquiry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254 , null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    service_requied = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SubCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Country', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    state =models.ForeignKey('accounts.State', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey('accounts.City', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False)
    defects = models.TextField(max_length=254, null=False)
    service = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.service.username
```

Comment: What is your question about the code you have shown? Was there any particular problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: I want that is when the user will fill the form and while filling the enquiry form,  in-service field the user can see on the staff user only not all user.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key relationship filtering is with double underscore. This might work:

```
Enquiry.objects.filter(service__is_staff=True)
```

The reference link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: That will work and give queryset. Please check out the link provided or post the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 from django.db.models import Subquery

 staff_users = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)   
 Enquiry.objects.filter(service_id__in=
                      Subquery(staff_users.values('id')))
```